# preg replace with method inside it

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
echo preg_replace("#\[map\](.+)\[\/map\]#e", '[link=maps.php/".$map_id[array_search("$1", $map_name)]."/$1/]$1[/link]', $text);
```

is my try.

I want to replace

```
[map]map_name[/map]
```

to

```
[link]maps.php/id/map_name[/link]
```

I have two arrays, `$map_id` and `$map_name`. They contain the exact same items and items are connected with the same key, eg: `$map_id[123]` that ID is for that map: `$map_name[123]`.

My `preg_replace` does not work as it returns: `Failed evaluating code: [link=maps.php/&quot;.in_array(&quot;ksz_luminous&quot;, $map_name).&quot;/ksz_luminous/]ksz_luminous[/link]`

Comment: Maybe [preg_replace_callback()](http://uk1.php.net/preg_replace_callback)?

Comment: I suggest you avoid using the `e` flag. It triggers deprecated notices in current PHP version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `e` flag. Suppose I used this:

```
[map]",array())].shell_exec("evil command of evil").$map_id[array_search("[/map]
```

Or something like that.

Anyway, try this:

```
echo preg_replace_callback("(\[map\](.+?)\[/map\])i",
    function($m) use ($map_id,$map_name) { 
        return "[link=maps.php/"
           .$map_id[array_search($m[1], $map_name)]
           ."/".$m[1]."/]".$m[1]."[/link]";
    }, $text);
```

Comment: Yours would return an error about unexpected function, but that is the way to go. Thanks